# Android Bluetooth Peripheral Mode Notification Descriptor

Tags: android, bluetooth, notifications

I am writing an Android app that acts like a BLE peripheral.

I have the `onDescriptorWriteRequest` `override` in my `BluetoothGattServerCallback` derived class.

When I subscribe for `notifications` from an `IOS` app called LightBlue this method gets called, but I can't seem to find any way to tell whether it is passing in `ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE` or `DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE`.

I found some code that I am basing this part on and they use the `description.getValue()` and compare it to those constants.

In my case `getValue() returns null` no matter what I choose.

The value parameter to `onDescriptorWriteRequest()` has a value, but it is a `long` value and only part of it changes to something seeming random each time, so I can't determine which would be enable and which would be disable if that is in fact what value is being used for. It has values like `[B@633adb and [B@690f978`.

Here is the code I am using:

```
        @Override
        public void onDescriptorWriteRequest (BluetoothDevice device, int requestId, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, boolean preparedWrite, boolean responseNeeded, int offset, byte[] value) {

        super.onDescriptorWriteRequest(device, requestId, descriptor, preparedWrite, responseNeeded, offset, value);

        Log.i(TAG, "onDescriptorWriteRequest, uuid: " + descriptor.getUuid());

        if (descriptor.getUuid().equals(UUID.fromString(notificationDescriptionUUID))) {
            if (descriptor.getValue().equals(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE)) {

                // this is how I keep track of which devices to notify later
                removeDeviceFromNotifyList(notifyDeviceList, device);
                notifyDeviceList.add(device);
            }
            else if (descriptor.getValue().equals(BluetoothGattDescriptor.DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE)) {

                // this is how I keep track of which devices to notify later
                removeDeviceFromNotifyList(notifyDeviceList, device);
            }
        }

        // now tell the connected device that this was all successfull
        mBluetoothGattServer.sendResponse(device, requestId, BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS, offset, value);
    }
```

Right now it crashes on `descriptor.getValue().equals` because `getValue()` is always `null`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onDescriptorWriteRequest` function is called when the central wants to assign a value to the descriptor. Assuming that your aim is to check if the central wants to subscribe/unsubscribe by checking for the `BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE` or the  `BluetoothGattDescriptor.DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE`

For this, just check if the `value` parameter equals either of these pre-defined constants.
The code can be as follows -

```
if ( Arrays.equals(value, BluetoothGattDescriptor.DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE))
{
 //Your disable code 
}
else if (Arrays.equals(value, BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE))
{
//Your enable code
}
```

I haven't tested this code. But I believe this should work.

Comment: AWESOME. Thank you so much. That was the trick. Before I had tried something similar. I had value.equals, but that didn't work. Again, thank you!